# how link to my .css file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a design problem with CodeIgniter. The path to my CSS file is defined like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/main.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

But it is not working properly.

Comment: You have to give more context and details. Read more about [how to ask a great question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will work,

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('asset/main.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

you can use url_helper,

```
if ( ! function_exists('base_url'))
{
    function base_url($uri = '')
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        return $CI->config->base_url($uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `<?php echo base_url(); ?>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>asset/css/main.css" />
```

in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In `config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Your `.htaccess` will be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

So your folder structurer would be like this

```
 1. application
 2. asset         
     1. css
        - bootstrap.css
        - main.css
     2. images
 3. index.php
 4. .htaccess
 5. system
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can check this.**

**In config.php:**

```
$config['base_url'] = URL;
```

**Go to**

applicatino/confg/autoload.php.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('html','url');

<link rel="stylesheet" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/stylesheets/main.css')?>"/>
//OR
<?php echo link_tag('assets/stylesheets/main.css')?>

//Image
<?php echo img('asset/images/learnersway.jpg')?>
//OR
<img src="<?php echo base_url('asset/images/learnersway.jpg')?>" />

//Javascript
<script src='asset/javascript/yourscript.js'></script>
```

**Visit this link:** https://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html

Answer (score 0):

1. first create a folder in the root

   Like   css// css folder   application  model  view

   than make the base url

   in config file  $config['base_url'] = 'localhost://codegniter/'; url
   of the site

   now if you want to include the css file in the site header  put the
   line like this in header or other file

   "
   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">